# How is Fedora 16 with proprietary software?

Tags: fedora

I was using Arch, Kubuntu and Ubuntu the most recently.

I am considering Fedora for a stable KDE environment.

But since the Fedora team is actively discouraging proprietary software like **Flash, NVidida drivers**, **wifi, bluetooth** and **MP3 support**, is it easy to actually install them without jumping through hoops and breaking your system?

Is there any "software bundle" for enabling all of the above, like Ubuntu has non-free-extras?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Licensing FAQ entry](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Licensing/FAQ#What_about_putting_Non-Free_items_in_a_separate_Non-Free_repository.2C_like_Debian.2FUbuntu_does.3F) *"What about putting Non-Free items in a separate Non-Free repository, like Debian/Ubuntu does?"*

> Fedora Project itself has no interest in this. [Third party repositories](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Third_party_repositories) exist for such purposes.

The [unofficial Fedora FAQ](http://www.fedorafaq.org) includes some details on the specific items you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there are repositories like rpmfusion which distinguish the free and non-free packages for Fedora, RedHat and Centos.

Detailed instructions on setting up the repository package configuration are listed at:
http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration/

Details on how to enable other repositories in a quick guide is at:
http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-prepare-other-yum-repositories-for-rhelcentos-5/

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Fedora with NVidia graphics cards, MP3 playback (and encoding), Flash, etc. for years, and it all works fine, although it needs some manual work.

I can confirm, that arguably, it is easier to set things up than with Ubuntu, since [RPM](http://rpm.org/) and [yum](http://yum.baseurl.org/) works quite good with adding stuff like that.

They're trying to make a statement with this kind of behavior. As in pushing towards OSS favorisation. I think that practice is OK, although it brings up problems here and there...

Comment: Want to note that "manual work" can be somewhat remedied with autoplus/autoten.